# Filter out character out of returned JSON object

Tags: c#, regex, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm busy developing an app for Windows Phone 7. The app basically calls a web service that then returns JSON content. I use the [Json.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to then take that JSON object that then gets converted to a C# object. For example, if the JSON content looked like this:

```
      {
           "FirstName" : "",
           "LastName" : "",
           "Gender" : ""
      }
```

A class would get created that looks like:

```
class person{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

So as you can see, the variables in the generated class matches the variables names in the JSON content exactly. E.g., FirstName → FirstName.

But now I've come to a stage where the returned JSON content has a variable with the name '**ID#**', and if you're a quick thinker you'll see that a C# variable is then going to get generated that will be named 'ID#', but obviously in C# you can't use the hash symbol in a variable name.

How can I get past this obstacle? I was thinking of filtering out the `#` symbols in the returned JSON content, but how exactly do I go about doing this, and is that even the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write:

```
class person{
   [JsonProperty("ID#")]
   public string ID { get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Just want to make sure what namespace 'JsonProperty' is from?

Comment: @DeanGrobler Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateMember` attribute of namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization` and your value `"ID#"`will be converted to `ID`, it is also supported by `Newtonsoft`

```
[DateMember(Name = "ID#")]  
public string ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Asif. I'm getting an error though stating that it's not finding DateMember as a type or namespace (Even with the namespace import).. Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid me, it's NewtonSoft.Json; My bad, my current document didn't contain that import. Thanks!